# RTTI behavior not appearing as expected

Tags: c++, rtti

I have written this code in MS Visual Studio Express 2012 to see the rtti behavior.
But it is not working as expected.
What is wrong in my code?

**Shape.h**

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape(){}
    virtual ~Shape(){}
    virtual double area() = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape
{
    int a;
public:
    ~Square(){}
    Square(int );
    virtual double area();
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
    int l;
    int b;
public:
    ~Rectangle(){}
    Rectangle(int,int);
    virtual double area();
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
    int r;
public:
    ~Circle(){}
    Circle(int);
    virtual double area();
};
```

**ShapeMain.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    Shape* c = new Circle(4);
    cout<< "Area of circle:" << c->area() << endl;
    cout << typeid(c).name();

    Shape* s = new Square(4);
    cout<< "Area of square:" << s->area() << endl;
    cout << typeid(s).name();

    Shape* r = new Rectangle(4,5);
    cout<< "Area of rectangle:" << r->area() << endl;
    cout << typeid(r).name();

}
```

**Output**

```
Area of circle:50.24
class Shape *           //Expected class Circle*
Area of square:16
class Shape *           //Expected class Square*
Area of rectangle:20
class Shape *           //Expected class Rectangle*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeid()` only actually performs an RTTI lookup when passed an lvalue of a polymorphic type. `Shape` is a polymorphic type, but you aren't passing a `Shape` lvalue, you're passing a `Shape*`. So when you are passing `c`, `s` and `r` to `typeid()`, it reports the static type of those expressions, which is `Shape*`.

To get a run time lookup you can either dereference your pointer: `std::cout << typeid(*r).name() << std::endl;`

or you can keep references directly:

```
Circle circle{4};
Shape& c = circle;
cout << "Area of circle:" << c.area() << endl;
cout << typeid(c).name() << endl;
```